# sendmail not working with chrooted php-fpm and nginx

Tags: php, nginx, sendmail, chroot

I'm running a multi-site setup with nginx and php-fpm 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04. All sites are chrooted and everything runs like a charm. Except mail() over sendmail. (php-fpm version should not matter here, I'm struggling with this since 7.1).

Sendmail and postfix are running and configured. This line sends an email.

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | /sbin/sendmail -t -i root@example.com
```

Trying "the same" via PHP does not work:

```
mail("foobar@gmail.com","Testing","It's a test.", "root@example.com");
```

Does not work. mail() returns false. The mail log (/var/log/mail.log) remains empty. I configured log for sendmail with

```
php_value[mail.log] = /logs/mail.log
```

This log shows the call, e.g.

> [16-Oct-2020 21:17:46 Europe/Berlin] mail() on [/htdocs/mail.php:8]:
> To: foobar@gmail.com -- Headers: root@example.com -- Subject: Testing

I also installed mini_sendmail (https://acme.com/software/mini_sendmail/), latest version, because I realised that sendmail requires a dozen files that I had to mount into my chrooted folders. So I downloaded mini_sendmail, renamed it to sendmail and put it into the chrooted folder **/var/nginx/example_com/usr/sbin/sendmail**

Running thes script from the command line with php, php-cgi also works:

```
php-cgi mail.php
php-cgi mail.php
```

phpinfo() also shows, that everything is configured (sendmail-path). shell-exec and exec are allowed functions. /bin/sh is also within the chroot-jail. Everything seems to be okay.

Any ideas, what I'm missing here? I don't even get an error message, that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here with centos 7, nginx 1.18, php-fpm 7.4.

Sending mail from PHP web app (mantisbt) - nothing happened, all server logs were empty (nginx error.log, php-fpm error.log, maillog, messages, selinux audit, ...)

Sending from commandline was working fine:

```
php -r'mail("user@domain.tld", "Subject", "Body");'
```

---

SOLVED

We finally found out that an invalid sender email address (From:) caused the trouble. After fixing from address, everything is working fine.

---

Some helpful links:

[PHP mail function not working on Centos server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341678/php-mail-function-not-working-on-centos-server)
https://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15398

Comment: I also tried the sender-email-address-trick, without success. Would you mind being more precise about that? You provided the from-address as an argument for mail()? What does "invalid" mean? Didn't fit what email address, configured where? Thanks!

Comment: Pse have a look at line 1362 in email_api.php
https://github.com/mantisbt/mantisbt/blob/master/core/email_api.php#L1362

Comment: Invalid address means we passed the string "user.domain.tld" instead of "user@domain.tld"